# Switching Ruby versions using homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

One of the projects that I've been working has a dependency on `ruby@2.3`.

I'm using a Mac and the version of Ruby that I used for other projects is the `2.5`.

I want to temporarily switch from `2.5` to `2.3` using `brew`. I don't want to use neither `rbenv` nor `rvm`.

**1. I've installed the `2.3.7` version, using `brew`:**

`` bf-old> brew install ruby@2.3
    Warning: ruby@2.3 2.3.7 is already installed and up-to-date
    To reinstall 2.3.7, run `brew reinstall ruby@2.3 ``

**2. I'm trying to switch to it, but it's not working:**

`bf-old> brew switch 2.3.7
Error: 2.3.7 not found in the Cellar.`

What can I do about this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use established mechanisms (although I currently prefer asdf) for switching? It's much easier and more reliable. In any case, have you `brew doctor`ed first? And are you running the `brew` you think you are (e.g., https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/25647)

Comment: Yeah, I'd use `rbenv` or `rvm` and curious why you are ruling those out.

Comment: I like to run terminal sessions inside of Emacs using `multiterm`. It's not so easy and straightforward to mirror environment variables needed by something like `rvm` inside of it, so I just avoid it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521112/using-rvm-in-eshell-of-emacs . This is one of the reasons. The other one is that I was curious as to how to make this work / why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if both the ruby versions are installed.
If both are installed, then try this:

```
brew unlink ruby@2.5 && brew link --force --overwrite ruby@2.3
```